# changing icon foundry = search and replace class names snafu

Tags: html, css, sass

When we change an icon foundry, it causes a minor snafu in that a lot of code needs to be revisited because icon names change. Some automated translation might be possible using text utils, but not when icon names are generated in a structured way (e.g., i-star-filled v/s i-star-empty based on a boolean).

What I want instead is to use functional names for my icons (such as xyz-search, xyz-cancel, xyz-filterable, etc.) and then map them to the actual icon name provided by the foundry. For example, glyphicon names might be different from those used by font awesome. How can I provide some kind of indirection (the same kind of liberation that HTML tags strong and em provide)?

Our first thought was to use a lookup table in javascript to translate from one namespace into another. But that works only when the HTML is being generated (we use angularjs); not helpful for static code, nor in those few cases where the icon name is generated computationally, as in the example in the first para.

So now we are toying with SASS (I have googled a fair bit but all in vain, nor is my CSS very shiny). Is there a SASS idiom that fits here, to translate something like

```
<i class="xyz-filterable ...">
```

to

```
<i class="i-funnel ...">
```

for the same visual and interaction outcome. (I understand the actual CSS will look quite different)

I do not want to use any foo.addClass().

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [@extend](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend):

Sass:

```
.xyz-filterable {
  background-image: url(foo.png);
}

.i-funnel {
  @extend .xyz-filterable;
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```
.xyz-filterable, .i-funnel {
  background-image: url(foo.png);
}
```

Comment: But I do not have any `foo.png` image for my icon.

Comment: @Dinesh since you didn't supply any CSS, that rule is just meant to be an example of how `@extend` works.